# How do you solve for the sum of the series

Tags: sequences-and-series

From the question$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}112*(0.065)^n$$My way of approaching is by trying to find the limit of the partial sum of a series but I can't get a general formula for the partial sum. Am I missing another easier way of approaching this?

Comment: This is just a geometric series.

Comment: My bad, I've been editing and trying to attempt the question for like 20 mins now and that was my previous question.

Comment: So I tried the infinite geometric series formula and got 119.7. I don't think that's right however

Comment: Be careful of the first term!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The first term of the series is $112\times 0.065$ (not $112$). (Make sure you know why this is!) Then use the formula for an infinite geometric series.

Comment: OHHH I see, my first term was off, you were right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Observe that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a\cdot b^n=a\sum_{n=1}^\infty b^n$$
$$=a(b+b^2+...)=a(1+b+b^2+...)-a$$

Then use that $$x\neq 1 \implies 1+x+...+x^n=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$$

Hint: what is $\lim_{n\to\infty}b^n$, given some $0<b<1$?

Answer (score 0):

From comments: "So I tried the infinite geometric series formula and got 119.7. I don't think that's right however"

$1 + 0.65 + 0.65^2 + ......  = \frac 1{1-0.065} \approx 1.070$ and so

$112( 1 + 0.65 + 0.65^2 + ......) \approx 119.7$

.... but...

also from comments.

"Be careful of the first term!"

$\sum_{k=0}^\infty 0.065^n= 1+0.065 + 0.065^2 + .... \approx 1.071$

*but* $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 0.065^n = 0.065 + 0.065^2 + 0.065^3 + ..... =$

either $(\sum_{k=0}^\infty 0.065^n) - 1$ or $0.065*(\sum_{k=0}^\infty 0.065^n)$.  Either way you get $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 0.065^n= \frac 1{1-0.065} -1 = \frac {0.065}{1-0.065} \approx 0.0695$ and

Our answer is $\approx 7.786$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}112 \cdot (0.065)^n = 112\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}0.065^n= 112 \cdot \frac {0.065}{1-0.065}$$

because $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}0.065^n$$ is a *geometric series with the first element $a_1 = 0.065$ and the quotient $q_1 = 0.065$, too.*
 Because $|q|<1$, the series is convergent, and we may use known formula
$$\sum = \frac {a_1}{1-q}$$

for it.

So the result is $$112\cdot \frac {65}{1000-65}=\frac {112\cdot65}{935}=\frac {112\cdot 13}{187}=\frac{1456}{187} \approx 7.78609625668449
 $$

Answer (score -1):

According to the general expression for the partial sums of the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula):
$$\sum_{n=1}^N ar^n=ar\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} r^n=ar\frac {1-r^N}{1-r}.$$

If $|r|<1$ (as in your example) the sum will tend to
$$\frac {ar}{1-r}. $$

Now substitute $a=112$, $b=0.065$.

Comment: What would be the value for N? The sum goes to infinity which is what I had confusion with.

Comment: @user Avoid giving out results like this freely, instead guide the asker to this result, which is then easy to apply

Comment: @RhysHughes What result do you mean?

Comment: The sum of a geometric series. Instead of just giving it out, show the steps to finding it (as my answer did)

Comment: @RhysHughes I have added a link to the commonly known derivation of the formula. I should admit that your answer adds little to this common knowledge.

Comment: @RandomStudent I thought you were interested in the general expression for the partial sum, rather than in its limit for $N\to\infty$. Now I have added also the latter expression.